# Python - update a class self dictionary inside a class function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary declare in a class (self.d1).
After calling f1 function, self.d1 need to be update to a local dict declare inside f1

```
import copy

class num:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
        self.f1(self.d1)

        print self.d1

    def f1(self,d):
        d2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
        d = copy.deepcopy(d2)

test = num()
```

I expect the output to be:

```
{'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
```

but the output is

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

I want to understand what the problem is and not only the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to assign to `d` in `f1()`, as that loses the old binding it had to `self.d1`. So after the assignment `d` is just a local variable of `f1()`.

But you can achieve what you want with this:

```
class num:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
        self.f1(self.d1)

        print self.d1

    def f1(self,d):
        d2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
        d.clear()
        d.update(d2)

test = num()
```

**output**

```
{'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}
```

Note that my code makes no assignment to `d` in `f1()`, it only makes calls that *mutate* the existing object.

For further reference on this & related topics, please see this excellent article by SO stalwart, Ned Batchelder: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that with

```
d = deepcopy(...)
```

you're not altering the dictionary that `d` referred to, you just change `d` to refer to another dictionary (in this case, to a newly created copy of a dictionary).

Comment: So there is anyway to altering the original dictionary d was referred to?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a value `{'a' : 1}` to some variable `self.d1` then that variable keeps a reference to the value. This means that you can change the values of `d1` by accessing it such as: `self.d1['a'] = 2`, and now the value will be `{'a' : 2'}`.

You can also change the reference of the variable `self.d1` by assigning it to something new. So in your function `f1` you actually change the reference that `d` points to, not the value it referes to. And because of the scoping of the function, `self.d1` will still keep its reference to your original value outside the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yust an other explanation ...

```python
class num:

    def __init__(self):

        self.d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
        # calling a function with a dictionary copies the *reference* to the
        # dictionary object.

        print 'first test ..'
        self.test_dict_arg_1(self.d1)
        print self.d1

        print 'second test ...'
        self.test_dict_arg_2(self.d1)
        print self.d1

    def test_dict_arg_1(self, d):

        d2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
        # now you load d with a new value, the referenced object is untouched
        d = d2

    def test_dict_arg_2(self, d):

        d2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
        # now you work with the referenced object
        d.clear()
        d.update(d2)
```